# macOS - Getting JSON data from Raw Github + Parsing

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to get json from a `githubusercontent` (URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json) into a Swift file then converting it into something that I can manipulate, for example, using `enabled` (below) to have a checkbox checked/unchecked.
The JSON in question is actually an array of JSONs, and this is the main problem. I'm not sure if the code below will work, because I haven't imported the JSON.

So far, I've found this:

```swift
struct ModsJSON: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool
    let hidden: Bool
    let icon: String
    let categories: Array<String>
    let actions: Array<OptionAction>?
    let warning: ActionWarning?
}

let jsonData = JSON.data(using: .utf8)! //JSON being the imported json
let mods_json: [ModsJSON] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([ModsJSON].self, from: jsonData)
```

I am a beginner in swift, and I realize that this should be easy, but I can't find a practical answer anywhere.

macOS Big Sur - Latest Swift and Xcode versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy for a beginner, you have to load the data asynchronously with `URLSession`.

Some of the keys in the JSON dictionaries are missing, therefore you have to declare more struct members as optional.

The types for the keys `actions` and `warning` are missing, I commented them out, the code works without them, too

```
struct Mod: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool?
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: [String]?
    // let actions: Array<OptionAction>?
    // let warning: ActionWarning?
}

let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Mod].self, from: data!)
        print(result)
    } catch { print(error) }
}
task.resume()
```

There are some bad practices in your code:

- Instead of `try!` use always a `do - catch` block if an error could occur.
- Variable names in Swift are `lowerCamelCase` rather than `snake_case`.
- Don't annotate types the compiler can infer.
- Structs used in an array should be named in singular form (`Mod`) and the *JSON* suffix is pointless.

Comment: "Don't annotate types the compiler can infer" I don't agree with that one. You can speed compilation way up by helping the compiler infer types.

Comment: @matt In my experience beginners often disimprove things by annotating types 

Answer (score 1):

Vadian is correct. Whatever is not present in any of the elements of the array must be marked Optional:

```
struct ModsJSON: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool?
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: Array<String>?
    // let actions: Array<OptionAction>?
    //let warning: ActionWarning?
}
```

Your code will then successfully parse the JSON. You can then, as you say, learn all the `enabled` values by saying eg.

```
let enableds = mods_json.map {$0.enabled}
```

But some of the elements lack the `enabled` so you would have to decide how to deal with that. The results appear as

```
[Optional(true), Optional(true), nil, Optional(true), Optional(true), Optional(true), Optional(true), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, Optional(false), nil, Optional(false), Optional(false), nil, Optional(false), Optional(false), Optional(false), nil, nil]
```

How to reflect this data into your interface is a totally different problem!

Comment: So both of these answers seem to be supposed to work, but when I use them within a SwiftUI (I've imported `foundation`) it returns errors saying that Expressions are not allowed at the top level. I assume I either need to use it within another swift file, which I have no clue how to do, or create a function, but I've messed around with that and nothing seems to work. I appreciate the answers, and I'd like to mark them as correct, but so far it isn't working.
I feel like I've missed something glaringly obvious...

Comment: But that is unrelated to the actual question you asked.