# MacOS - Using a JSON array to add entries to a SwiftUI list

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Some time ago, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589324/macos-getting-json-data-from-raw-github-parsing) involving decoding JSON. I am using this JSON to create an entry in a list and decide whether or not to have a checkbox ticked.
My previous question asked how to decode the JSON, and I have this code which looks useful (below), but to be honest, I have no idea what to do with.

Where would I put this within a SwiftUI file where I could loop through each piece of JSON in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json) array and add an entry into a SwiftUI?

I have experience with Python, and I understand how it should be done, but am quite the beginner in swift...

My code:

```swift
struct Mod: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool?
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: [String]?
    // let actions: Array<OptionAction>?
    // let warning: ActionWarning?
}

let modsURL = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Mod].self, from: data!)
        print(result)
    } catch {print(error)}
}
task.resume()

let mods_test: () = importJSON(url: modsURL)
let enableds = mods_test.map {$0.enabled}
```

If there is anything wrong with this question, please tell me! Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Serach for 'SwiftUI List'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a struct to match this Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423755/how-to-create-a-struct-to-match-this-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, how you can do that,

you can use `State` to declare variable

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //Declare variable
    @State var jsonDataList = [jsonData]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(jsonDataList, id: \.id) { jsonDataList in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(jsonDataList.id)
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text(jsonDataList.display)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: jsonDataList.enabled ?? false ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Web Service

    func loadData() {

        guard let modsURL = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: modsURL) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonData].self, from: data!)
                jsonDataList = result
                print("Response:",jsonDataList)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
    }
}

// MARK: - Data Model

struct jsonData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool?
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: [String]?
}
```

Response Screenshot :

[image]