# MacOS - Using JSON to format SwiftUI list with checkboxes (continued)

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-list

Yesterday, I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757086/macos-using-a-json-array-to-add-entries-to-a-swiftui-list/66757594#66757594).
I now have this script:

```swift
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
struct Mods_UI: View {
    @State private var falseerror = false
    @State var jsonDataList = [jsonData]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(jsonDataList, id: \.id) { jsonDataList in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(jsonDataList.display)
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text(String(jsonDataList.description))
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: jsonDataList.enabled ?? false ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
    }

    func loadData() {

        guard let modsURL = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: modsURL) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonData].self, from: data!)
                jsonDataList = result
                print("Response:",jsonDataList)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
struct Mods_UI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Mods_UI()
    }
}

struct jsonData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    let enabled: Bool?
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: [String]?
}
```

I would like to format the checkbox: `Image(systemName: jsonDataList.enabled ?? false ? "checkmark.square": "square")` as a Toggle: `Toggle("", isOn: $jsonDataList.enabled)`. I have tried a few ways of formatting this, and it always seems to return an error. My plan for this is to be able to check if the box is checked, and if so, install a file somewhere.

Another thing that I'd like to do is only show the items in the JSON that either have `jsonDataList.hidden` as `false` or just do not have `jsonDataList.hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to happen in order to make this work. The first is that your model should probably have `enabled` be a `var` instead of a `let` -- that way, its value can be changed when the `Toggle` is manipulated:

```
struct jsonData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let display: String
    let description: String
    let url: String?
    let config: Bool?
    var enabled: Bool? //<-- Here
    let hidden: Bool?
    let icon: String?
    let categories: [String]?
}
```

Next, you'll need to create a Binding to use with the Toggle. Because your model is in an array, the Binding will need to know which item to update (its index in the array). You'll see that in my code as the `enabledBindingForIndex` function.

Lastly, in order to get the index for each item that you'll be passing into the `enabledBindingForIndex` function, the `ForEach` code will have to be changed a little bit so that it passes in both the JSON item *and* the index. I like using `.enumerated()` for this. Note that the `id` of the item is now `.1.id` because you'll be getting a tuple with both the index (`.0`) and the item (`.1`). I also filter out the hidden items in that same line.

```
struct Mods_UI: View {
    @State private var falseerror = false
    @State var jsonDataList = [jsonData]()

    func enabledBindingForIndex(index: Int) -> Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool> { () -> Bool in
            return jsonDataList[index].enabled ?? false
        } set: { (newValue) in
            jsonDataList[index].enabled = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(Array(jsonDataList.filter { $0.hidden != true }.enumerated()),  //<-- Here
                 id: \.1.id) { (index,jsonDataList) in //<-- Here
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(jsonDataList.display)
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text(String(jsonDataList.description))
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Toggle(isOn: enabledBindingForIndex(index: index)) { } //Here
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
    }

    func loadData() {

        guard let modsURL = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nacrt/SkyblockClient-REPO/main/files/mods.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: modsURL) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonData].self, from: data!)
                jsonDataList = result
                print("Response:",jsonDataList)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

If you wanted to have some side effect that takes place when the `Toggle` is enabled/disabled, you could do so in the `enabledBindingForIndex` `set` closure.